# WebStorm unresolved variable window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, webstorm

Basicly, I'm trying to develop an app by using AngularJS,Ionic and Apache Cordova.
I get a couple of "unresolved variable" warnings within WebStorm 8 like the ones below:

```
angular.module('recordsApp', ['ionic']).run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    //unresolved variable Keyboard
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
    }
    //unresolved variable StatusBar
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      //unresolved variable or type StatusBar
      //unresolved method of function styleDefault()
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

### What I did

- I created my project with a ionic-blanc-template
  `$ionic start mapp blank`

### What I allready tried

- enabled HTML in Settings>JavaScript>Libraries
- Checked if angular.js is part of my project
- Checked the projects' structure

### My expected result

I should get a blank page with a navigation bar at the top of the screen 
which includes a couple of UI elements (like buttons and stuff)

### The actual result

A blank page with a gray bar at the top of the screen which says
"Ionic Blank Starter"
My guess is that this default screen is caused by the unresolved variables and functions

- I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit
- Webstorm 8
- Latest versions of Cordova, AngularJs and Ionic

If you need any more details please feel free to ask me!

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the warnings caused by unresolved variables.
**I had to delete the code created by the template since it overwrites every other output**